# Object doesn't support this property or method: JavaScript

Tags: jquery

I'm using the tipTip jQuery tooltip plugin but in IE I keep getting the "Object doesn't support this property or method" on the following line:

```
$(function(){
    $(".scrolltotop").tipTip({defaultPosition: 'top'});
});
```

jQuery and the plugin are being loaded before I call the function so a non-existing function can't be the cause.

Could anybody help me to figure this out?

EDIT

jQuery is being loaded only once. I've collected all the JavaScript functions into a separate file. In fact those codes should not affect each other. However there's another function which is being triggered on clicking on the same element:

```
$(function() {
    $(".scrolltotop").click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Could this be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: There's a good chance you're loading jquery twice, once before tip tip and once again after.

Comment: Any chance you could provide some sort of [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) by way of, say, [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [jsbin](http://jsbin.com)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are missing the js plugin reference that provides the tipTip function.

Comment: It exists. More than that - everything works fine in all other browsers. The problem is in IE only.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this post solved it:

> There's a good chance you're loading jquery twice, once before tip tip and once again after. – Vadim Jun 8 at 19:14

I was loading jQuery twice due to the fact that I needed different versions of jQuery and jQuery UI for older versions of IE.

I simply moved the Tooltip script below my last jQuery and it worked fine, thanks Vadim.

Sorry I can't help on your problem though, Cycero.

Cheers